# Codeigniter controller / model / library naming

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying find out, what's the **best practice** for controller / model / library naming convention in codeigniter.

To simplify, I will explain the problem on PayPal example. The requirement is to have the controller name (in this case the keyword paypal) in the URL.

The **controller** will be **paypal.php**

The **model** will be **paypal_model.php**

The **library** will be **Paypal_lib.php**

There are 2 problems with this approach:

1. Controllers are almost never called by their names. Models on the other hand are called by names all over the project. This mean, that I will end up with **$this->paypal_model->doSomething()** instead of cleaner way - $this->paypal->doSomething (or $this->user->getEmail, etc...) There are 2 options how to achieve the result, but I won't call neither of them best practice:

   - name the controller (file and class) something like paypal_controller.php and create route for it ($route['paypal'] = 'paypal_controller'). You can imagine how things get complicated when you have couple of functions /w parameters in that controller. And to be consistent, all your controllers should be routed this way.
   - rewrite the logic in codeigniter system directory (I'm not sure if this changing files in system directory is good idea)
2. There is similar problem with libraries. Adding suffix to every library is working, but it is inconsistent with system libraries ($this->pagination->create_links() vs $this->paypal_lib->create_links())

I'm not sure if there is a solution for this, or it's just a codeigniter "limitation".

Comment: I'm not quite getting the question but when you load a model or controller you can pass a second argument, a name, which is what you refer to it as when you want to access it

Comment: [You didn't read the CI documentation I guess.  The "best practices" and recommendations are spelled out clearly.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/styleguide.html)

Comment: The question is in first sentence - what is the best practice for naming controllers / models / libraries. @xd6_ thank you, you partially answered my question. It is possible to pass the second parameter if the model is auto-loaded?

Answer (score 3):

For model at the time of loading you can give alternate name to the model and then use this name in controller for function call .. like this.
model name is payapel_model.php
                              $this->load->model('payapel_model','paypal');
                            then when call for function
                                $this->paypal->doSomething();

Answer (score 1):

Controllers you can use either capital letter like so **Your_controller.php** or **your_controller.php** either way is OK for lib files is same but prefer capitals for models either **mdl_yourname** or **model_yourname**. HMVC Is very useful.

if you are calling model from folder

```
$this->load->model('payment/paypal_model');
$this->paypal_model->yourfunction();
```

or

```
$this->load->model('payment/mdl_paypal');
$this->mdl_paypal->yourfunction();
```

Make sure in model you add word mdl or model. Because some times codeigniter gets confused.

```
$route['paymentwhatever'] = "folder/payment_paypal/index";
$route['paymentwhatever'] = "folder/payment_paypal/yourfunction";
```

They are most common. Also look at there user guide very help full the user guide is.